# Ajax.ActionLink giving 404 not found error

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404

I have a partial view that has an `Ajax.ActionLink` that when clicked should replace the view (target DIV) with another partial view that allows a user to upload an image. I have several of these on the page that work, I just can't seem to figure out why I keep getting a 404 for this particular one.

Here's what I have:

MyProfile.cshtml holds all the partials (tenant-reference-photos is update target DIV):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 well-border" id="tenant-reference-photos">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Tenants/_TenantReferencePhotosPartial.cshtml", Model)
    </div>
    <div class="span6 well-border" id="tenant-viewings">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Tenants/_TenantViewingsPartial.cshtml", Model)
    </div>
</div>
```

_TenantReferencePhotosPartial.cshtml (ActionLink giving 404 here):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
@if (Model.ReferencePhotos == null)
{
    <h3>You haven't uploaded any references! 
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Upload now?", // on click 404 returned in developer tools in Chrome
        "UploadReference",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "tenant-reference-photos",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader"
        })
    </h3>
}
</div>
```

Code below returns the above partial:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult TenantReferencePhotos()
{
    var currentTenant = tenantRepository.GetLoggedInTenant();
    return PartialView("_TenantReferencePhotosPartial", currentTenant.ReferencePhotos.ToList());
}
```

The following `ActionResult` is what's not being invoked in the `Ajax.ActionLink` and giving the 404 error:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadReference(HttpPostedFileBase file, Tenant tenant)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 10240)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("file", "The size of the file should not exceed 10 KB");
            return View();
        }

        var supportedTypes = new[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG" };
        var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Substring(1);

        if (!supportedTypes.Contains(fileExt))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("photo", "Invalid type. Only the following types (jpg, jpeg, png) are supported.");
            return View();
        }

        using (var db = new LetLordContext())
        {
            var reference = db.Image.Create<ReferencePhoto>();

            // Convert HttpPostedFileBase to byte array
            MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
            file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
            byte[] photo = target.ToArray();

            reference.File = photo;
            reference.Format = fileExt;
            reference.DateUploaded = DateTime.Now.Date;
            reference.Description = "";
            reference.Name = "";

            db.Image.Add(reference);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return PartialView("_TenantReferencePhotosPartial", file);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

For completeness, here's the partial view where an image can be uploaded:

```
<div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadReference", "Tenants", FormMethod.Post,
   new AjaxOptions
   {
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       UpdateTargetId = "tenant-reference-photos"
   }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        Select a file:
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="UploadReference" />
    </div>
}
</div>
```

All scripts in MyProfile.cshtml are referenced. Does unobtrusive-ajax.js need to be included as a script in all partial views even if it's referenced in Layout.cshtml and/or MyProfile.cshmtml?

Can anyone spot why I'm getting the error above?

Answer (score 2):

In your code `UploadReference` is decorated with `HttpPost` attribute so it is accessible only when you make POST. In your view you have configured `HttpMethod` to GET. When you change it to `POST` it should work:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Upload now?",
    "UploadReference",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "tenant-reference-photos",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader"
    })
```

Comment: Leaving my code as is, I think I should have a GET ActionResult that returns the partial _TenantUploadReferencePartial? Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, you have right - instead oh changing `HttpMethod` in your view you can remove `HttpPost` attribute. But in my opinion you should separate two case. First action when you want return view only and it work with GET. Second action for POST that support upload logic.

Comment: I've done as I described above, but now I'm getting a 500 error. When I step through the GET ActionResult in debug mode, it reaches return PartialView but it's not actually updating the target DIV, and I'm getting the 500 error in the client. I'll keep looking into it.